# Scrape multiple pages from a website without being blocked

Tags: python, scrapy

When we try to scrape one url with this website there is no problem, but when we try more than one we get this:

```
2017-05-11 15:37:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://www.liberation.fr/debats/2017/05/03/pourquoi-marine-le-pen-peut-gagner-et-pourquoi-il-faut-le-dire_1566941http://www.liberation.fr/france/2017/05/05/calais-et-grande-synthe-deux-visages-des-migrations-en-france_1567534http://www.liberation.fr/elections-presidentielle-legislatives-2017/2017/05/04/a-l-etranger-un-scrutin-scrute_1567355> (referer: None)
2017-05-11 15:37:16 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 http://www.liberation.fr/debats/2017/05/03/pourquoi-marine-le-pen-peut-gagner-et-pourquoi-il-faut-le-dire_1566941http://www.liberation.fr/france/2017/05/05/calais-et-grande-synthe-deux-visages-des-migrations-en-france_1567534http://www.liberation.fr/elections-presidentielle-legislatives-2017/2017/05/04/a-l-etranger-un-scrutin-scrute_1567355>: HTTP     status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-05-11 15:37:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

DOWNLOAD_DELAY is fixed to 5 seconds and CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN to 1 but it changes nothing...
How could we solve that issue ?
Thx :)

[Edit] my bad, I forgot commas in my list of urls, problem solved sorry for the topic !

Comment: Look at the first line of your log, you have url concatenated twice, so it is obviously either typo or error in url generation.

Comment: The page doesn't exist, that's why you get a 404

Answer (score 1):

Normally they got a good reason to block scraping, always try and see if they can provide the information via an API or any other type of feed, I have found that this is the case if your reason is serious and valid for getting the info you are need of.

Otherwise your solution is the TOR network which will give you a new IP for every request. Here is a short article https://deshmukhsuraj.wordpress.com/2015/03/08/anonymous-web-scraping-using-python-and-tor/

Comment: You can also use [crawlera](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera/). (not free)